# Using selection sort with an array of strings in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm having issues producing the correct result on this selection sort. I feel as if the code is correct and the logic works, but to my current understanding the result I'm getting are incorrect. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void selectionSort(string[], int);
string linearSearch(string[]);

// Declare variables
    const int MAX_FRIENDS = 250;
    int currentIteration = 0;
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    // Declare stream file
    fstream names;
    names.open("myFriends.txt");
    string friends[MAX_FRIENDS];
    while(getline(names,friends[currentIteration])){
        currentIteration++;
    }
    cout << "Before Sort:\n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < currentIteration; i++){
        cout << "Index " << i << ": " << friends[i] << endl;
    }
    selectionSort(friends,5);
    cout << "\nAfter Sort: \n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < currentIteration; i++){
        cout << "Index " << i << ": " << friends[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Function Declaration

```
void selectionSort(string arr[], int num){
    // Declare Necessary Variables
    int startScan,minIndex, index;
    string minValue;
    for(startScan = 0; startScan < (num - 1); startScan++){
        index = startScan;
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = arr[startScan];
        for(index = (startScan + 1); index < num; index++){
            if(arr[index] < minValue){
                minValue = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

I am working with a text file of myFriends that contains the following names in the following order

1. Samuel Said
2. Louise Stephen
3. Stephen Wakefield
4. Patty Anderson
5. John Hoover

When I run the selection sort I get this sequence back in this order.

1. Louise Stephen
2. John Hoover
3. Patty Anderson
4. Samuel Said
5. Stephen Wakefield

To my knowledge of ASCII these are not correct values. Please inform.

Comment: This isn't a free debugging service, and we expect you to show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. Learning to debug your programs is an important part of learning to code. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `index` twice.

```
    for(index = (startScan + 1); index < num; index++){ // increment it here
        if(arr[index] < minValue){
            minValue = arr[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
        index++; // and increment it also here
    }
```

So you're only checking every other element of the array.

Get rid of the second `index++;` line.

Comment: Results changed here, but they are still incorrect.
Now I have
 1. John Hoover
 2. Louise Stephen
 3. Patty Anderson
 4. Samuel Said
 5. Stephen Wakefield

Comment: @austintice What do you think the correct order should be?

Comment: I imagined that the correct order would relate to the combined ASCII values of each so it would go(shortened): Samuel, J, L, P, Stephen

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "combined ASCII values". J is before S, so John Hoover is before Samuel Said.

Comment: It's lexicographic: First compare the first characters. If they're the same compare the second characters. Keep repeating until you get to a character that's different, and use the ordering of those characters.

Comment: I was under the impression that you didn't sort the values based solely on their first character, but on their cumulative ASCII value count. As if you were doing `stoi(str)`

Comment: Your impression is wrong. Numeric types are sorted arithmetically, strings are sorted lexicographically.  `123 > 20` is true, `"123" > "20"` is false.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one logical error. `index` is being incremented twice per iteration of your inner loop.